# Зависает сетевой интерфейс Debian

Tags: debian, linux

Здравствуйте.

Моя VDS постоянно зависает, то есть, становится недоступен как сайт, размещенный на нем, так и не могу приконнектиться по SSH.

В саппорте ответили:

```
Вы не корректно настроили работу сервисов Samba и NetBios. В результате чего, через определенное время сетевой интерфейс зависает, после перезагрузки его, интернет вновь появляется.
```

Зависания происходят примерно каждые 5 минут.

Возможно, кто-то поможет мне решить данную проблему? (В линуксе ноль)Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Зачем вам на VDS Samba и NetBios?  Выключите их и все.

Вообще похоже на бред. Выясните у тех поддержки конкретно, что значит “не корректно настроили работу сервисов Samba и NetBios”. Пускай дадут развернутый ответ.

Возможно у них просто с железом проблемы.

Comment: @huffman, удалил Samba, а саппорт — не может решить проблему.В данный момент не наблюдаем ни описанной Вами проблемы, ни каких-либо проблем в работе сети на Вашем VPS, которые отражались бы в логах или при анализе трафика. VPS работает стабильно, и доступен без каких-либо проблем.(Хотя ВДС лежит)После чего попросили трассировку, пинг и т.д, я им отослал, после чего их ответ был таким — «Соберите пожалуйста статистику за более длительный период, необходимо чтоб в статистику попала информация во время не доступности Вашего заказа.»Видимо, на ТП надежды никакой, только сменить хост?

Comment: Собирать статистику,  в которую попадёт недоступность сервиса, очевидно же

Comment: @ArcherGodson, то есть я должен месяц собирать статистику и ждать, пока закончится ВДС? :о

Comment: Вы же говорите, что "вдс лежит каждые 3 минуты", это и есть критерий недоступности. Зачем ждать месяц?! Просто в трейсах, что вы отправляли техподдержке проблемы видимо даже с вашей стороны не было, а тем более с вдс